# What is the recommended culture volume for HeLa cells and seeding number for 384 well plate wells?

Tags: cell-culture

For 24 well plate wells, [thermofischer](https://www.thermofisher.com/de/de/home/references/gibco-cell-culture-basics/cell-culture-protocols/cell-culture-useful-numbers.html) recommends to seed 0.05E6 cells with 0.5 to 1 ml of medium. What are recommended numbers for a 384 well plate well?

Answer (score 0):

[The Privalsky Lab@ UCDavis writes](http://microbiology.ucdavis.edu/privalsky/tc-growth-area):

Growth Area of Tissue Culture Plates and Dishes

```
    Growth Area (cm2)   Media Volume (ml)   Maximum Volume (ml)
Plates           
 35 mm            8          1.6- 2.4    
 60 mm           21          4.2- 6.3    
100 mm           44          11 -16.5    
150 mm          148          30 -45  
245 mm (square) 500         100-150  

Dishes           
  6 well        9.5         1.9  -2.0       16.8
 12 well        3.8         0.76 -1.14       6.9
 24 well        1.9         0.38 -0.57       3.4
 48 well        0.95        0.19 -0.28       1.6
 96 well        0.32        0.1  -0.2        0.36
384 well        0.056       0.025-0.05       0.125

Flasks           
 T25             25          5- 7.5  
 T75             75         15-22.5  
T150            150         30-45
```